# Text not appearing in list element blocks

Tags: html, css, text, position

I am currently doing an assignment and I cannot figure out why the text in the orange container list is not in the orange boxes. The boxes are in the position that I would like them to be in, but I do not understand why the letters are in a completely different space. Shouldn't the text associated with the element move together with the element? I mean, why are the pink boxes okay, but not the oranges ones. I appreciate any help!

[This is what my issue looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0a1k.png)

```css
 main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.blue-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  background-color: #141f40;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
  
}
.white-container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:220px;
}
.white-container>li{
  background-color: #a9004b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #80bfa8;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.red {
  background-color: #8c2727;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
.orange-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 180px;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.orange-container>li{
  background-color: #ff863f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #d98d30;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

/* from yahoo ui */
  html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}ol,ul{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;*font-size:100%}legend{color:#000}#yui3-css-stamp.cssreset{display:none}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Puzzle 3 Farshad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css"-->
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="blue-container">
      <div class="top">Top</div>
      <ul class="white-container clearfix">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="left">Left</div>
      <div class="red">Red</div>
      <ul class="orange-container">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: The external stylesheet is not available via HTTPS, so it won’t load here in the SO snippet. I tried to copy&paste the content over to your snippet, but it still doesn’t look like your screenshot, there aren’t even any orange boxes. Please edit & fix this, so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry! I do not know what happened! I fixed it and the problem shows up in the SO snippet. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact that your `.red` element is floated (as is the `.left` element). This means that any text content in that area will float *around*  it - in this case it's pushed down. Normally, this would make the first `li` element higher to an extent that its text ("A") is still inside its orange background, but * under*  the floated red area. But since you are restricting the height of the `li` elements to 50px, the `li`s themselvess stay where they are, nevertheless, their contents are pushed down - outside of the borders of those `li`.

If you want to keet the situation as you have it, i.e. two floated elements next to each other and the third sibling element `.orange-container` on top of the second one (`.red`), you have to use `position: absolute` and adjust the position settings as shown in the snippet below (where I only set them approximately to give you a general impression).

```css
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.blue-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  background-color: #141f40;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
  
}
.white-container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:220px;
}
.white-container>li{
  background-color: #a9004b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #80bfa8;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.red {
  background-color: #8c2727;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
.orange-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.orange-container>li{
  background-color: #ff863f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #d98d30;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

/* from yahoo ui */
  html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}ol,ul{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;*font-size:100%}legend{color:#000}#yui3-css-stamp.cssreset{display:none}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Puzzle 3 Farshad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css"-->
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="blue-container">
      <div class="top">Top</div>
      <ul class="white-container clearfix">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="left">Left</div>
      <div class="red">Red</div>
      <ul class="orange-container">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

But I would recommend to do it differently: Make `.orange` a child element of `.red`,  remove `float: left` from `.red` and `.left` and instead apply `display: inline-block` (and `vertical-align: top;`) to them (and still make `.orange` a child element of `.red`, with relative position and according `top` and `left`settings:

```css
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  
}
.blue-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  background-color: #141f40;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
  
}
.white-container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:220px;
}
.white-container>li{
  background-color: #a9004b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #80bfa8;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.red {
  background-color: #8c2727;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.orange-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.orange-container>li{
  background-color: #ff863f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #d98d30;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

/* from yahoo ui */
  html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}ol,ul{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;*font-size:100%}legend{color:#000}#yui3-css-stamp.cssreset{display:none}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Puzzle 3 Farshad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css"-->
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="blue-container">
      <div class="top">Top</div>
      <ul class="white-container clearfix">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="left">Left</div><div class="red">Red
        <ul class="orange-container">
          <li>A</li>
          <li>B</li>
          <li>C</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Note also that I moved the opening tag of `<div class="red">` up to follow directly after the closing tag of the previous element to avoid whitespace between those two inline-blocks.